# error when linking cplex to netbeans for c++

Tags: c++, netbeans, cplex

I am trying to link cplex (version 12.6.2) to netbeans (version 8.2) for c++ on Mac OS Yosemite (10.10.4). When I import an existing project from a colleague and I run the main file, everything works fine and it produces a solution. When I do any modification on the main file, I get the following error message:

```
cd '/Users/user/Desktop/user '
/usr/bin/make -f Makefile CONF=Debug
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
"/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/milp_techreport
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX
rm -f "build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main_TechRep.o.d"
g++ -stdlib=libstdc++   -c -g -DIL_STD -I../../Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1262/cplex/include -I../../Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1262/concert/include -I/Applications/biogeme-2.5/libraries/linearAlgebra -I/Applications/biogeme-2.5/libraries/utils -I/Applications/biogeme-2.5/libraries/randomNumbers -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main_TechRep.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main_TechRep.o main_TechRep.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX
g++ -stdlib=libstdc++    -o dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/milp_techreport build/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/main_TechRep.o -L../../Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1262/cplex/lib/x86-64_osx/static_pic -L../../Applications/IBM/ILOG/CPLEX_Studio1262/concert/lib/x86-64_osx/static_pic -lconcert -lcplex -lilocplex -lcplexdistmip
0  0x10825b172  __assert_rtn + 144
1  0x108294af6  archive::File<x86_64>::makeObjectFileForMember(archive::File<x86_64>::Entry const*) const + 1138
2  0x108293e90  archive::File<x86_64>::justInTimeforEachAtom(char const*, ld::File::AtomHandler&) const + 122
3  0x1082ae431  ld::tool::InputFiles::searchLibraries(char const*, bool, bool, bool, ld::File::AtomHandler&) const + 265
4  0x1082b7710  ld::tool::Resolver::resolveUndefines() + 160
5  0x1082b9a6f  ld::tool::Resolver::resolve() + 79
6  0x10825be90  main + 812
7  0x7fff902365c9  start + 1
A linker snapshot was created at:
/tmp/milp_techreport-2017-02-21-155344.ld-snapshot
ld: Assertion failed: (memberIndex != 0), function makeObjectFileForMember, file /Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/ld64/ld64-253.3.3/src/ld/parsers/archive_file.cpp, line 355.
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-MacOSX/milp_techreport] Error 1
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2
```

We have compared our configurations and they looks the same. Any ideas what this may be due to?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: `Assertion failed: (memberIndex != 0)` this failure might be the key.

Comment: And do you have an idea of what the solution could be?